# Set property value based on some properties

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like set `ButtonDisabled` property to `false` in these conditions :
At least one property with suffix `_Set1` is true and at least one property with suffix `_Set2` is `true`. When the conditions are no longer met set `ButtonDisabled` property to `true`

An idea how do this ?

```
public bool CheckBox1_Set1 { get; set; }

public bool CheckBox2_Set1 { get; set; }

public bool CheckBox3_Set1 { get; set; }

public bool CheckBox1_Set2 { get; set; }

public bool CheckBox2_Set2 { get; set; }

public bool CheckBox3_Set2 { get; set; }

public bool ButtonDisabled { get; set; }
```

Comment: Do you want to _set_ the value of `ButtonDisabled`'s backing-field, or do you want `ButtonDisabled` to be a computed property (without a backing-field) that returns `false` when other properties/members meet certain conditions?

Comment: You'll have to write the code for this. It would be easier if instead of individual properties you had a `bool[]` property, or if all the `CheckBoxN` properties used an array as backing field. In that case you could use `_array1.Any() && _array2.Any()` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This?

```
class Smurf
{
    public Boolean CheckBox1_Set1 { get; set; }
    public Boolean CheckBox2_Set1 { get; set; }
    public Boolean CheckBox3_Set1 { get; set; }

    public Boolean CheckBox1_Set2 { get; set; }
    public Boolean CheckBox2_Set2 { get; set; }
    public Boolean CheckBox3_Set2 { get; set; }

    private Boolean Set1HasAtLeast1True => this.CheckBox1_Set1 || this.CheckBox2_Set1 || this.CheckBox3_Set1;
    private Boolean Set2HasAtLeast1True => this.CheckBox1_Set2 || this.CheckBox2_Set2 || this.CheckBox3_Set2;

    public Boolean ButtonDisabled => !( this.Set1HasAtLeast1True && Set2HasAtLeast1True );
}
```

Example:

```
void Main()
{
    Smurf s = new Smurf();
    s.CheckBox1_Set1 = true;
    s.CheckBox2_Set2 = true;
    Console.WriteLine( "Should be false: {0}", s.ButtonDisabled );
    
    s.CheckBox1_Set1 = true;
    s.CheckBox2_Set2 = false;
    Console.WriteLine( "Should be true: {0}", s.ButtonDisabled );
}
```

Screenshot proof:

[image]

Comment: It's a solution but I thought at an observer I search all the time the complexity :)